# Is there a way to change the background colour of the view for 1 second whenever the state changes in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, redux

Is there a way to change the background colour of the view for one second then change it back to normal colour , whenever the state changes in react native ?
How to approach this problem ? should we keep track of previous state and compare and make the blink , I am not getting any idea ?
sorry if my question is silly, I am a beginner and still learning .

Answer (score 0):

Try this (based on your duplicate question):

```
    this.setState({backgroundcolor:"#98fb98"},()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
    this.setState({backgoundcolor:'#previouscolor'})},1000)
    })
```

I'm using a callback of setState with a setTimeout that delays the second setState of 1000 milliseconds